# Inclusions satisfying homotopy equivalence

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I have this problem from my book *Algebraic Topology* by Glasner:

> Prove whether or not there exist inclusions $f : X \hookrightarrow Y$ and $g : V \hookrightarrow W$ so that $X$ is homotopy equivalent to $V$ and $Y$ is homotopy equivalent to $W$, but $Y \setminus X$ and $W \setminus V$ are not homotopy equivalent.

I think there aren't such inclusions; and here's my attempt at a proof:  We claim that there are no such inclusions. To see this, assume that there exist inclusions $f : X
\hookrightarrow Y$ and $g : V \hookrightarrow W$ so that $X$ is homotopy equivalent to $V$ and $Y$ is homotopy
equivalent to $W$, but $Y \setminus X$ and $W \setminus V$ are not homotopy equivalent. Then there exist continuous
maps $h : X \to V$ and $k : V \to X$ such that $h \circ k \simeq \mathrm{id}_V$ and $k \circ h \simeq \mathrm{id}_X$, and there
exist continuous maps $l : Y \to W$ and $m : W \to Y$ such that $l \circ m \simeq \mathrm{id}_W$ and $m \circ l \simeq
\mathrm{id}_Y$. We now claim that $l \circ f \circ k \simeq g \circ m \circ h$. To see this, define
$$\begin{cases}
  H : X \times [0, 1] \to W \\
  (x, t) \mapsto
  \begin{cases}
    l(f(x)) & 0 \leq t \leq \frac{1}{2} \\
    l(f(k(h(x)))) & \frac{1}{2} \leq t \leq 1.
  \end{cases}
\end{cases}
$$
Then $H$ is continuous, and $H|_{X \times \{0\}} = l \circ f \circ k$ and $H|_{X \times \{1\}} = g \circ m \circ h$.
Thus $l \circ f \circ k \simeq g \circ m \circ h$.

Is this proof right? Is my intuition correct? Is there a way to make the solution more precise?

Comment: Consider the 2-dimensional closed disc, where $x^2+y^2 \leq 1$. Suppose that W=Y is this disc. If $X$ is the origin, and $V$ is the line segment from $(-1, 0)$ to $(1, 0)$. Are $X$ and $V$ homotopy equivalent? What are the connected components of $Y\backslash X$ and $W\backslash V$?

Comment: Or even simpler, Let $X = Y = W = \mathbf{R}$ and $V = (0, \infty)$.

Comment: $m \circ h$ is not defined.