# Properties of inclusions in spaces [proof verification]

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

> Give an example of a pair of inclusions $f_0 : X_0 \hookrightarrow Y_0$ and $f_1 : X_1 \hookrightarrow Y_1$ so that $X_0$ is
> homotopy equivalent to $X_1$ and $Y_0$ is homotopy equivalent to $Y_1$, but $Y_0 \setminus X_0$ and $Y_1 \setminus X_1$ are
> not homotopy equivalent.

The question is taking from the book I'm self-read, Introduction to Topology by Vassili. This is my attempt (sorry for bad english):

Consider spaces $X_0 = S^1 \times \{0\}$, $X_1 = S^1 \times \{1\}$, $Y_0 = D^2 \times \{0\}$, $Y_1 = D^2 \times \{1\}$, where $S^1$ is unit circle, and $D^2$ is unit disk. Define inclusions $f_0 : X_0 \hookrightarrow Y_0$ and $f_1 : X_1 \hookrightarrow Y_1$ with $f_0(x, 0) = (x, 0)$ and $f_1(x, 1) = (x, 1)$. Now $X_0$ is homotopy equivalent to $X_1$ by homeomorphism $h : X_0 \to X_1$ defined as $h(x, 0) = (x, 1)$, and $Y_0$ homotopy equivalent to $Y_1$ by homeomorphism $g : Y_0 \to Y_1$ defined as $g((x, y), 0) = (x, y,  1)$. However, complements $Y_0 \setminus X_0$ and $Y_1 \setminus X_1$ do not have homotopy equivalent. Also, $Y_0 \setminus X_0$ deformation retracts to boundary of $D^2 \times \{0\}$, which is homeomorphic to $S^1$, as well as $Y_1 \setminus X_1$ that deformation retracts to boundary of $D^2 \times \{1\}$, which is homeomorphic to $S^1$. Although $Y_0 \setminus X_0$ and $Y_1 \setminus X_1$ are individual homotopy equivalent to $S^1$, there is no homotopy equivalence between these because their correspond to different boundaries of disks in $Y_0$ and $Y_1$.

Is it correct?

Comment: This is not correct, assuming you've written what you want correctly. $Y_1$ is homeomorphic to $Y_0$ in such a way that takes $X_1$ to $X_0$. $Y_1\setminus X_1$ and $Y_0\setminus X_0$ are really just the same thing - the open disc $D^2\setminus S^1$ - just with an extra product $\times\{0\}$ or $\times\{1\}$, so are also homeomorphic. Conceptually, you've taken "the exact same thing" in both cases (multiplying by $\{0\},\{1\}$ is just a set theoretic weirdness, it does not change the topology and essentially does nothing)

Comment: Also, if I understand you right, $Y_1\setminus X_1$, which is the open unit disc, does *not* deformation retract onto a circle. In fact it deformation retracts onto a point!

Comment: Ooh... I made many mistakes, I can see now. How can I fix this? Does such an example exist even? I try to think about the problem but I didn't find a better solution.

Comment: Many, many, many examples exist. Take $X_0,X_1,Y_0,Y_1$ all contractible spaces. Maybe even take $Y_1=Y_0$ and $X_0=X_1$. Can you find a contractible subset of, say, $\Bbb R$, and two ways to embed a contractible subspace into it that have fundamentally different complements?

Comment: The same question was asked 2 days ago: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4846980

Comment: @PaulFrost I don't see the question before. I should delete this one then?

Comment: @Jaclyn I closed the other question because your question was answered.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is not correct.

1. $Y_i \setminus X_i$ does not retract to the boundary, it is a copy of the open disk $U = \{ z \in \mathbb R^2 \mid \lVert z \rVert < 1 \}$.
2. Anyway, $Y_0 \setminus X_0$ and $Y_1 \setminus X_1$ are homeomorphic, thus also homotopy equivalent.

Here is an example:

$X_0 = Y_0 = X_1 = \{0\}$, $Y_1 = [0,1]$. The inclusions $X_0 \hookrightarrow X_1, Y_0 \hookrightarrow Y_1$ are homotopy equivalences. [Also the inclusions $X_i \hookrightarrow Y_i$ are homotopy equivalences, but that is irrelevant for the question.]  But $Y_0 \setminus X_0 = \emptyset$ and $Y_1 \setminus X_1 = (0,1]$ which are not homotopy equivalent.